# RowNumber in Sql from View WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

```
SELECT CatalogName AS Catalog,
       ProductID,
       CreateDate,
       RowNumber
FROM   (SELECT Catalog    AS CatalogName,
               ProductID,
               CreateDate,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                              (ORDER BY CreateDate DESC, ProductID) AS RowNumber
        FROM   Ad_Archive_Optimized
        WHERE  Brand LIKE 'r%') AS BasicSource
WHERE  BasicSource.RowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 25
ORDER  BY RowNumber
```

I have this query and I get an error at the first Where. I've tried almost everything and I know its a simple solution but I don't know what is the problem.

Ad_Archive_Optimized  is a view that has the exact values selected above so that is not the problem. The problem is at the following Where. Basically I'm asking if the where statement after my view will filter the results shown there ?

**LAter Edit:**
I've located the issue. The problem is adding the filter to the view (first where)

Comment: "I get an error at the first Where". What error?

Comment: So is this sorted now? Care to mention the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you meant

```
WHERE BasicSource.RowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 25 ORDER BY RowNumber
```

Comment: I will add it to my code and if no more issues .. I will accept answer

Comment: Hmmm ... the Where issue persists